# Show/prove that the solution of a 1st order linear DE can be written in the following form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

Here's the problem:

**(1) (a) Show that the solution of the linear equation $y'+p(t)y=g(t)$
can be written in the form
y=cy1(t)+Y(t), where c is an arbitrary constant. 
Identify the functions y1(t) and
Y(t).**

So I'm trying to solve the general DE $y'+p(t)y=g(t)$ for y... I'm trying to use the integrating factor μ(t) to do so, where $μ(t)p(t)=μ'(t)$. I just plugged back in μ(t) to $(μ(t)y)'=g(t)μ(t)$ but now I'm having trouble putting it into the form they're looking for, which is $y=cy1(t)+Y(t)$.

Right now I have:

> $$y=\dfrac {\int \mu(s)g(s)ds+c}  {\mu(t)} $$

How would you put it into the form above?

Comment: notice that $cy_1(t)$ general solution to $y'+p(t)y=0$ and $Y(t)$ is a particular solutin to $y'+p(t)y=g(t)$ and sum of them gives the general solution to  $y'+p(t)y=g(t)$

Answer (score 1):

You have already  proved that  $$y=(1/μ(t))[∫μ(s)g(s)ds+c]$$

Note that  $$y=(1/μ(t))[∫μ(s)g(s)ds] +c/μ(t)$$

Let $$y_p = (1/μ(t))[∫μ(s)g(s)ds]$$

and $$y_h =c/μ(t)$$

Then $$ y= y_p + y_h$$